# Create table from query result when it isn't null

Tags: postgresql, create-table

I want to create a table from a select query in PostgreSQL using "SELECT table myTable As SELECT...". The problem is it always creates a table even the query returns null. I know I can use of "SELECT Exist(select 1 from myTable)" to determine if the table is empty or not. My question is that can I combine this two SQL commands to one query that checks if the result is not null then create the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following PL/SQL:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM some_table) THEN
    SELECT your_table AS SELECT * FROM some_table
END IF;
END
$do$
```

Note that you need put the above `IF` statement into a `DO` block as I have done, or into a function; it won't work if executed directly from pgAdmin.